# Remove autofocus feature from android.permission.CAMERA on intel xdk

Tags: android, cordova, android-permissions, intel-xdk

I try to make a application with **Intel XDK**. I use "camera Object" (`intel.xdk.camera.importPicture()`).

The application works fine, but now I have a new  element. `android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS`.

`AUTOFOCUS` feature is not compatible with some devices in playstore. I don't need this feature on my application. I found on some forums that I need to change the template of the *Cordova* Android manifest (delete autofocus line).

But I don't know how to remove autofocus using The Intel sofware XDK.

Comment: There is no permission named `camera.AUTOFOCUS` in Android.

Comment: Sorry it's : android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS source : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: That is not a permission. That is a the name of a `<uses-feature>` element, one that you would put in a manifest (`AndroidManifest.xml`) to indicate that the device must have autofocus capability to be able to run your app.

Comment: Yes, it's true, I change the question! Thank you